# trust in vs confide in

Tags: difference

[collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/confide):
**(1)** *They **confided in** their own ability*.
my variant:
**(2)** *They **trusted in** their own ability*.
What is the difference between (1) & (2)?

[britannica.com](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/trust):
**(3)** *They **trust in** God*.
my variant:
**(4)** *They **confide in** God*.
What is the difference between (3) & (4)?

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/trust-in):
**(5)**  *You have to **trust in** the competence of others*.
my variant:
**(6)**  *You have to **confide in** the competence of others*.
What is the difference between (5) & (6)?

Comment: Did you look up the definition of **confide** in any of those dictionaries?  For example, in Oxford Learner's Dictionaries, it says "confide: to tell somebody secrets and personal information that you do not want other people to know" which seems very different from *trust*.

Comment: You can use _to have confidence in_ as a synonym of _to trust_, but not _to confide_.

Comment: @KateBunting you say: to trust = to have confidence in ≠ to confide. But "_to trust_" and "_to confide_" are not discussed in the original post. The question is about "_to trust in_" and "_to confide in_". Could you explain please what you meant?

Comment: @Loviii "to trust in" and "to confide in" are just the verbs "trust" and "confide" with prepositional phrases after them. They're not different verbs. "confide" ≠ "trust", no matter the context. "Confide" is a specific physical action". "Trust" is a belief.

Comment: _They confide in God_- they tell God their secrets. _They have confidence in God_ - they trust God.

Comment: @gotube you say: "Confide" is a specific physical action. Could you please explain what you mean by it using (1): _They confided in their own ability_. Where is a specific physical action in (1)?

Comment: You will very rarely (if ever) encounter the usage displayed in "confided their own ability." It is totally swamped by the verb form which "confers trust" on others. Obviously one cannot confer trust to/upon oneself.

Comment: @Loviii My apologies. I didn't read your question properly. I have never heard "confide" used to mean to have full trust; have faith. I would have marked that sentence incorrect. I'm surprised to find that in two major dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

In 19th Century British English, one meaning of "to confide" was "to be confident".  Before the sea battle of Trafalgar in 1805, Admiral Nelson wished to make a flag signal to his fleet, assuring his sailors that their country was confident that they would do their best.  He asked his signaller to hoist a set of flags, using "confides" in this context.  On being told that he could do it with fewer flags by substituting a single flag which meant "expects" for single letter flags spelling out "confides", he agreed, and the famous signal "England expects that every man will do his duty" was hoisted. Nowadays, that meaning is never used, and one confides in someone else by telling them a secret.  Obviously one trusts that person not to pass on the secret.